# A conversation about a Christmas gift

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, seasonal

The Christmas fever has already arrived. So yesterday I saw the following weird conversation in a chat room:

> -${}$ You know, I figured out what to buy ou for Christmas.
>   - What?
>   - I'll tell you on Christmas Ive.
>   - But I can't wait till then!
>   - You are smart! I am sure you will figure it aut.
>   - I will kill you!
>   - Stop being such a drama queen. Or should a say drama quing? See what I did? See?
>   - Oh, come on. That's not even remotely funny.
>   - Shall we go to the bub instead?
>   - The what?
>   - The pub. Sorry, slip of the fimgers.
>   - Are you drunk?
>   - Nope. I just drank some jin.
>   - You are drunk.

I am now wondering what the gift is? Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let's look at which letters have been changed:

> - You know, I figured out what to buy **[]** ou for Christmas.
> - I'll tell you on Christmas **I**ve.
> - You are smart! I am sure you will figure it **a**ut.
> - Stop being such a drama queen. Or should **a** say drama **qu**ing? See what I did? See?
> - Shall we go to the **b**ub instead?
> - The pub. Sorry, slip of the fi**m**gers.
> - Nope. I just drank some **j**in.

This should be:

> - You know, I figured out what to buy **y**ou for Christmas.
> - I'll tell you on Christmas **E**ve.
> - You are smart! I am sure you will figure it **o**ut.
> - Stop being such a drama queen. Or should **I** say drama **k**ing? See what I did? See?
> - Shall we go to the **p**ub instead?
> - The pub. Sorry, slip of the fi**n**gers.
> - Nope. I just drank some **g**in.

The new letters we get are:

> YEOIKPNG, which anagram to ... KEYING OP? EGO PINKY?

Or rather (thanks @LukasRotter!) the following:

> [image]

Thanks to @Techidiot for spotting

> some of the hidden letters in this image. I bleached the background so as to spot them more easily:
>
>  [image: bleached]

And we have the letters

> SSPPLEIR, which anagrams to **SLIPPERS**,

the final answer.

Comment: Almost there...

Comment: If you interpret the corrected letters "*yEoIkpng*" as an i.stack.imgur link: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yEoIk.png

Comment: Yay, thanks @LukasRotter! Not sure how I missed that a/o swap.

Comment: The image is nice, but what is the answer to the question of "*what the gift is*"?

Comment: @oleslaw All done!